# My code throws stackoverflowexception when i execute

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I am working on a Windows Application Development in c# language.
I have a template form => Masterpage which is inherited by all my other forms.

It has menustrip to open all other forms as well:

my error reads:

```
System.StackOverflowException
  HResult=0x800703E9
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

my Masterpage code is:

```
namespace WindowsProject
{
    public partial class Masterpage : Form
    {
        BookEditor bookE;
        StudentEditor studentE;
        ViewBorrowedBooks viewB;
        IssueBook issueBook;

        public Masterpage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bookE = new BookEditor();
            studentE = new StudentEditor();
            viewB = new ViewBorrowedBooks();
            issueBook = new IssueBook();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void showForm(Form f)
        {
            bookE.Hide();
            studentE.Hide();
            viewB.Hide();
            issueBook.Hide();
            this.Hide();
            f.Show();
        }

        private void booksToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showForm(bookE);
        }

        private void studentsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showForm(studentE);
        }

        private void viewBorrowedBooksToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showForm(viewB);
        }

        private void issueBookToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showForm(issueBook);
        }
    }
}
```

all my other forms inherits from Masterpage

Comment: Do forms `BookEditor`, `StudentEditor` and others inherit from `MaterHomePage`?

Comment: Yes they inherit from MasterPage

Comment: That's the reason of the `StackOverflowException`. Why do you need to create them in the constructor of the `MasterPage`?

Comment: to instantiate their objects and show them when I click their respective menus

Comment: Is it wrong?Whan do you suggest?

Comment: Does each of the inheritors of the `MasterHomePage` have its own `ToolStrip` and though this `ToolStrip` you can navigate to other inheritor (eg. from `BookEditor` to `StudentEditor`)?

Comment: yes they do have ie.

Comment: but we cannot navigate to the masterpage.

Comment: and the menustrip is the one of the template page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Why does `StackOverflowException` occur?***

`StackOverflowException` occurs because of the infinite recursion inside the constructor of the `Masterpage`.

*Lets consider how this recursion occurs.* `BookEditor` inherits `Masterpage`. (The following conclusions are also applicable to the other inheritors of the `Masterpage`). I suspect that `BookEditor` has a single constructor without parameters `BookEditor()`. In `C#` if you call constructor without parameters of the derived type it by default calls constructor without parameters of the base type (if you don't explicitly specify other constructor of the base type). Lets assume that we want to create an instance of the `Masterpage`. We call its constructor `Masterpage()`. Inside it we call constructor of the `BookEditor`. But `BookEditor` inherits `Masterpage` and therefore it calls constructor of the `Masterpage`. Constructor of the `Masterpage` again calls constructor of the `BookEditor` and etc. These sequence of the constructor calls leads to the infinite recursion and `StackOverflowException` as a result.

---

***How should you fix this problem?***

I think that more information is needed to thoroughly answer this question.

As a workaround you should create inheritors of the `Masterpage` outside of its constructor:

```
public partial class Masterpage : Form
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Form> _forms;

    public Masterpage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Now we set forms here, not in the constructor.
    public void SetForms(IEnumerable<Form> forms)
    {
        _forms = forms;
    }

    private void showForm(Form f)
    {
        foreach (Form form in _forms)
            form.Hide();

        this.Hide();
        f.Show();
    }

    // Other members of the Masterpage.
    ...
}

// Palce this code where you create and show Masterpage.
var bookE = new BookEditor();
var studentE = new StudentEditor();
var viewB = new ViewBorrowedBooks();
var issueBook = new IssueBook();

var forms = new List<Form> {bookE, studentE, viewB, issueBook};
bookE.SetForms(forms);
studentE.SetForms(forms);
viewB.SetForms(forms);
issueBook.SetForms(forms);

var masterPage = new Masterpage();
masterPage.SetForms(forms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering my question.
The problem i found on my code was it was looping infinitely since i put a child form inside the parent MDI form and instantiated the child form inside parent form’s constructor.
The problem was solved by instantiating the forms outside the constructor inside a method.